# jQuery: how to reference an HTML element whose class name has a period?

Tags: jquery

I have several elements in this way `<td class="sede_co.uk">`

I want to reference them using jquery this way:

```
$(td.sede_co.uk)
```

but jquery doesn't "find" them because (I guess) the point between "co" and "uk".

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: it's called a period, by the way.

Comment: @tmont: Not in england it isn't. :)

Comment: @Chris - you just blew my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *should* fix the invalid class name...but to query for it as is, escape the `.`:

```
$("td.sede_co\\.uk")
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Abgda/). Please do fix the class though, `.` isn't a valid character in a class name...it'll cause fewer headaches.

Comment: + 1 for that, do never ever put dots in Class Names or Eric Meyer will hunt you down!

Answer (score 5):

Oh, come on now, Hannes.  I only hunt down people for things like `<p class="paragraph">`.

If I may, a slight correction.  `.` is a valid character when it's been escaped, just as nearly anything you can type on a keyboard.  (It should only require one backslash to escape, though; I'm not sure why JSfiddle thinks it needs two.)

Hogan, you're correct that the point is the reason jQuery isn't finding the elements.  That's because `$(td.sede_co.uk)` is saying "select any `td` element that has *both* `sede_co` and `uk` in its `class` attribute's value".

In other words, it would select `<td class="sede_co uk">` or `<td class="uk sede_co">` or even `<td class="sede_co anarchy inthe uk mate">`.  Note the spaces in those values, which maintain 'separation' between the different words.  Since your cell's `class` value is literally `sede_co.uk` the selector can't find it.  Escape it, and it can.

Or else you could stop using points in `class` names.  It'll probably be easier on you in the long run.