# Jquery check if the class exists

Tags: jquery, dom

I have an IP managing script with ranges and jquery search to check if IP is already used, I add class to each row for the IPs for that range, like this

```
<tr class="table_176 213.5.176.120 213.5.176.121 213.5.176.122 213.5.176.123 213.5.176.124" id="213.5.176.120-124" style="display:none;">
                        <td class="actualip" align="center" >213.5.176.120-124</td>
                        <td >5</td>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" ><a href="https://www.racksrv.com/portal/staff/clientssummary.php?userid=637" target="_blank"> Mike Burkett</a></td>
                        <td align="center" ><a href="https://www.racksrv.com/portal/staff/clientshosting.php?userid=637&id=1537">RS96</a></td>
                        <td ></td>
                        <td align="center" ><a href="https://www.racksrv.com/portal/staff/supporttickets.php?action=open&userid=637" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.racksrv.com/portal/staff/images/icons/ticketsopen.png" alt="Open Ticket for " title="Open Ticket for " width="16" height="16"/></a></td>
                    </tr>
```

And use the following JQ

```
$('#search').click(function() {
        $found = false;
        $ip = $('#value').val();
        if ( $("."+$ip).length ){
            alert("found");
        }

        if($found == false) {
            alert('The IP you searched for was not found!');
        }
    });
```

But this isn't working? Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: $('.213.5.176.120') <=> class="213 5 176 120" Dots in classnames should be avoided (or escaped in the jQ selector)

Comment: Your class name is invalid, it can't begin with a digit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names/449000#449000

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932058/jquery-how-to-reference-an-html-element-whose-class-name-has-a-period

Comment: So basically problem #1 is that your code is not valid. It's not valid HTML3, because that didn't have classes. It's not valid HTML4, because classes and ids cannot start with a digit. It's closest to valid HTML5, but still invalid because you have the obsolete `align` attribute and unclosed [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/named-character-references.html). (Don't use bare ampersands in URLs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my own mistake was answered by

"$('.213.5.176.120') <=> class="213 5 176 120" Dots in classnames should be avoided (or escaped in the jQ selector) "

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest your problem is being caused by the dots in your class names, if you *have* to store the IP addresses in a class name then something like this would work -

```
   var ip = '213.5.176.120'; 
   if ($("tr[class*='" + ip + "']").length){
        alert("found");
    }
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/eZCdf/

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm pretty sure that dot (.) are not valid in class name, and even if they are, I wouldn't use them. That's *confusing*.
By the way, according to the specs, class couldn't begin with a number.

> All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under the control of CSS. For example, the case-sensitivity of values of the HTML attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of URIs lies outside the scope of this specification. Note in particular that element names are case-insensitive in HTML, but case-sensitive in XML.
>   In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Check the [CSS Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters)

Second, you shouldn't use class to store metadata, jQuery provides a convenient method to do that, and it's simply called, [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Keep the classes for what they deserve, CSS.

Comment: Periods don't make class names invalid, just more difficult to select in CSS.

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure, but if they are not, they should be because that's really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said, the problem is your class.  It's easy to simply replace those dots with underscores and use those in your class name.  Here's a quick and dirty example: http://jsfiddle.net/LFfwZ/